# Passing constructor delegate or object for unmanaged resources

Tags: c#, unmanaged, idisposable, using-statement

In my (simplified) problem I have a method "Reading" that can use many different implementation of some `IDisposableThing`. I am passing delegates to the constructor right now so I can use the `using` statement.

**Is this approach of passing a delegate of the constructor of my object appropriate?**
My problem is that things like `List<Func<IDisposable>>` etc start looking bit scary (because delegates look like crap in c#) and passing in a object seems more usual and a clearer statement of intent.

**Is there a better/different way of managing this situation without delegates?**

```
    public void Main()
    {
        Reading(() => new DisposableThingImplementation());
        Reading(() => new AnotherDisposableThingImplementation());
    }

    public void Reading(Func<IDisposableThing> constructor)
    {
        using (IDisposableThing streamReader = constructor())
        {
            //do things
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get a good answer, this is a stylistic question which is mostly a matter of taste. We can't say whether it's better to have the `using` statement inside `Reading` without knowing more of what that method actually is. Likewise with `Func`s vs factories

Comment: @BenAaronson I think you're probably right. I'm going to come back and see if I can improve it, or at least share a little more of my context.

Comment: There is such a thing as looking for *too much* generalization.  I certainly would not enjoy having to read this kind of code.  Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, it's difficult to say what's best for your situation, so instead I'll just list your options so you can make an informed decision:

**Continue doing what you're doing**

Having to use around objects with an unpleasantly complicated-looking type is maybe not ideal visually, but in your situation it may well be perfectly appropriate

**Use a custom delegate type**

You can define a delegate like:

```
public delegate IDisposableThing DisposableThingConstructor();
```

Then anywhere you would write `Func<IDisposableThing>`, you can just write `DisposableThingConstructor` instead. For a commonly used delegate type, this may improve code readability, though this too is a matter of taste.

**Move the `using` statements out of `Reading`**

This really depends on whether it's sensible for the lifecycle management of these objects to be a responsibility of the `Reading` method or not. Given what we have of your code at the moment, we can't really judge this for you. An implementation with the lifecycle management moved out would look like:

```
public void Main()
{
    using(var disposableThing = new DisposableThingImplementation())
        Reading(disposableThing);
}

public void Reading(IDisposableThing disposableThing)
{
    //do things
}
```

**Use a factory pattern**

In this option, you create a class which returns new `IDisposableThing` implementations. Lots of information can be found on the factory pattern which you may well already know, so I won't repeat it all here. This option may well be overkill for your purposes here, adding a lot of pointless complexity, but depending on how those `DisposableThing`s are constructed, it may have additional benefits which make it worthwhile.

**Use a generic argument**

This option will only work if all of your `IDisposableThing` implementations have a parameterless constructor. I'm guessing that's not the case, but in case it is, it's a relatively straightforward approach:

```
public void Reading<T>() where T : IDisposableThing, new()
{
    using(var disposableThing = new T())
    {
        //do things
    }
}
```

**Use an Inversion of Control container**

This is another option which would certainly be overkill if used for this purpose alone. I include it mostly for completeness. Inversion of control containers like Ninject will give you easy ways to manage the lifecycles of objects passed into others.

I very much doubt this would be an appropriate solution in your case, especially since the disposable objects are not being used in another class's constructor. If you later run into a situation where you're trying to manage object lifecycle in a larger, complex object graph, this option might be worth revisiting.

**Construct the objects outside of the `using` statement**

This is specifically described as "not a best practice" in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx), but it is an option. You can do:

```
public void Main()
{
    Reading(new DisposableThingImplementation());
}

public void Reading(IDisposableThing disposableThing)
{
    using (disposableThing)
    {
        //do things
    }
}
```

At the end of the `using` statement, the `Dispose` method will be called, but the object will not be garbage collected because it is still in scope. Trying to use the object after that would be very likely to cause problems because it is not fully initialized. So again, while this is an option, it's unlikely to be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is this approach of passing a delegate of the constructor of my object appropriate?** My problem is that things like `List<Func<IDisposable>>` etc start looking bit scary (because delegates look like crap in c#) and passing in a object seems more usual and a clearer statement of intent.

Yes, it's fine. However I understand your concern about passing a list of those things... Perhaps creating a custom delegate with the same signature as `Func<IDisposable>` and a more explicit name (e.g. `SomethingFactory`) would be clearer.

> **Is there a better/different way of managing this situation without delegates?**

You could pass a factory or a list of factories to the method. I don't think it's really "better", though; it's mostly the same, since your factory would typically be represented as an interface with a single method, which is essentially the same as a delegate.